# Migrate Kubernetes storage from vSphere to NFS with StatefulSets

Tags: kubernetes, nfs, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-statefulset

I'm trying to move all my persistent volumes from vSphere to NFS, I managed to do it for many applications that use `Deployment` kind. All I have to do is:

- Mount the NFS volume to a different path (`/tmp` for example)
- Copy the data from vSphere volume to NFS volume (using `cp` command in the pod)
- Swap the volumes names in
  the `Deployment` definition and finally get rid of the vSphere volume

Now, I have StatefulSets with volumes to be mounted on each pod. This approach won't work since Kubernetes wont let you modify the field `spec.volumeClaimTemplates` in `StatefulSets` definition.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
...
spec:
...
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: data
      spec:
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 30Gi
```

I have 3 replicas and the vSphere volumes were provisioned dynamically, but I have now 3 NFS volumes that I created manually and I want to migrate the existing data to them.

Any idea how to perform this operation?

Comment: @Vega This is about devops and I saw similar questions here, I also posted this on serverfault.

Comment: There are 46.5k questions with kubernetes tag, don't you think "programmers" use this tool a lot?

Comment: Hello abdelhalimresu, could you add sts spec.volumeClaimTemplates section to the question? How did you set up a Kubernetes cluster (cloud, on-premise, k8s version)?

Comment: Actually it's not Kubernetes, it's openshift and it's running on-premise. I updated the question with volumeClaimTemplates snippet.

Comment: I'm rather looking for an approach or tool. Couldn't find anything on the internet.

Comment: you might need to 1) delete STS 2)modify PVC details in it 3) recreate it ..